# Firestore: how to validate array values and maps dynamic fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It's a classic of firebase validation: check if members reference actually exists, with the structure defined as shown in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

```
"members": {
    "firstUserId" : true,
    "secondUserId" : true,
    "thirdUserId" : true
}
```

In real-time database it was like

```
"members":{
  "$user_id":{ ".validate":"root.child('users/' + $user_id).exists() && newData.isBoolean() && newData.val() === true" }
},
```

but in Firestore we cannot cycle over documents fields, we can only validate fields of which we know the name, it seems.

Someone could say a solution would be to put those ids in a collection instead of a map, but that will prevent me from querying the documents like "all objects of which I'm a member".
Also, adding a collection seems really overkill given that the documents in that collection will be absolutely empty.

If I turn that map into a collection I'd also be forced to keep a map of objects IDs (or references) **also** on the users documents and retrieve the objects one at a time or with two requests the second of which would be "give me the collection of objects whose id is X or Y or Z or ....", which isn't an elegant solution.

Is there an elegant solution to this use case?